# Email is not deleting from gmail using pop.DeleteMessage

Tags: c#, gmail

I am downloading emails from gmail by using **MailBee.Pop3Mail's pop3** class. I want to delete email from my inbox by using Pop3 class's **DeleteMessage** method but it's not deleting the email from my gmail inbox even after calling Pop3 class's **Disconnect()** method.

That's my POP/IMAP configuration in my gmail account
[image]

And that's my c# code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this methos don't work with gmail.

> Note that some servers may, for instance, not let you delete e-mail
> via POP3 or may simply ignore the deletion request. The typical
> example of a non-standard POP3 and IMAP behaviour is Gmail.
> [See Gmail IMAP and POP3 issues topic](https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/getting_started_with_imap_pop3.html#GmailIssues) for details.

Comment: So how can I delete email from gmail account after downloading it?

Comment: @AamirNakhwa use the gmail api?